# How can I make a live counter that counts the passwords generated from a txt file in python?

Tags: python, counter

```
import random

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 

numbers = "123456789"

while 1:
    password_len = int(input(" What length for the passwords: "))
    password_count = int(input(" How many passwords would you like to generate: "))
    txtfile = open('passwords.txt','w')
    for x in range(0,password_count):
      password = ""
      for x in range(0,password_len):
        password_char = random.choice(chars + numbers)
        password = password + password_char
      txtfile.write(password + '\n')
    txtfile.close()
    print("Generated: ") #<--counter`
```

I would want some help, bellow is a gif with the live counter.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzULp.gif

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Well, you can do `print(x,end='\r')` inside the loop, but the printing is going to slow things down.  You can generate them WAY faster than you can print numbers.  Maybe print every 100th time?

Comment: Why is this in a `while 1:` loop?  And you can use `random.choices` to get your whole password at once.  You don't need a loop.  Also, you shouldn't be using the same variable (`x`) for both loops.

Comment: To answer your question, we need to understand where you want to display the counter.  Is it displayed on a web site, in a GUI, etc.  Since, this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

This prints the count every 1,000 lines:

```
for x in range(password_count):
  password = ""
  for _ in range(password_len):
    password += random.choice(chars + numbers)
  if x % 1000 == 0:
    print(x,end='\r')
  txtfile.write(password + '\n')
```

For 100,000 passwords, it only takes 2.5 seconds, so there's not much to see.